# Rigid body chain with armature breaks

Tags: armature, physics, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to make a chain rigid body simulation. I found I wanted to streamline it more, so I could rotate a bone to move the end/start, and I added a bone constraint to it as well, so that I can't pull the two too far apart and break the simulation.

However, when the bones in the armature begin to move, the simulated chains attached to it fall through, The settings applied below are nearly identical on all chains.

[image]

Settings changed:

- Mesh shape
- Sensitivity margin lowered
- (Chain with bone) Animated
- (Chain with bone) Deforming

Is it possible to have chains with rigged bones? If so, how would I fix my simulation to that it properly animates without the chains falling through?
Thank you.

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/4f90cbccb0d6410e91d629d621e1f16c

Here you go. I was able to figure out a bit of a round about fix as well. I'm not sure why it works. 

Having the objects be stand alone objects, with "child of" constraints it fixes the animation. However, you need to delete the weight painted ones. If you know why this happens and how to weight paint them and have them work, I'd love to hear why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want but maybe it will help, I've deleted *Armature.001*, deleted all the keyframes of the links, made the first and last link *Type > Passive* instead of *Active*, put the origins at geometry and added edge loops:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah yes this works, thank you! This is exactly what I had wanted and was looking for. Would you mind explaining why this fixed it up, or linking a good tutorial explaining?

I'm not sure about why it worked, but it didn't explode like the last few attempts, and quite a few videos I watched didn't talk about why physics work like this. Even if you don't though, thank you so much for helping. I can copy this next time it messes up.

Comment: if you choose Shape > Mesh it needs enough topology to correctly calculate the interactions, otherwise it bugs, I think it was the main problem here